# What does "as_text_trimmed" do?

Tags: perl

I have some Perl code here and one line says...

```
my $newlink = $link->as_text_trimmed;
```

I know it means that the variable `$newlink` is given the value of the `$link` variable calling on `as_text_trimmed`. But, I can't find any info on the web on what `as_text_trimmed` does. Can anyone tell me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Presumably, `$link` is an object from a module you are using in the script, and `as_text_trimmed` is one of that modules subroutines. It's impossible for us to determine what module that is, you have to check your source code and see what modules are used.

Comment: just find the declaration of $link, it should be like my $link = Some::Module->new(); and then look on cpan.org (or google) for the module and then method definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [quick search of CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=as_text_trimmed&mode=all) yields [HTML::Element](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aElement)

> $h->as_trimmed_text(...) as_text_trimmed
>
> This is just like
>   as_text(...) except that leading and trailing whitespace is deleted,
>   and any internal whitespace is collapsed.
>
> This will not remove hard spaces, unicode spaces, or any other non
>   ASCII white space unless you supplye the extra characters as a string
>   argument. e.g. $h->as_trimmed_text(extra_chars => '\xA0')

Answer (score 1):

$link is some kind of data structure and as_text_trimmed is a field in it.
You aren't setting $newlink to $link. You are setting it to a field within the link object.

as_text_trimmed could also be a method on the link object that you are calling and setting newlink to it's result.

Do a search on perl's "arrow operator"